# How to write a function that uses a pandas data frame variable as input?

Tags: python, function, pandas, seaborn

I would like to write a function that will generate a plot and take a variable as input.  I am new to `Python` and have more experience with `R`.  I have seen function that involve a variable from a `pandas` data frame generally use `apply()` but I don't know how to conditionally select rows based on Group.

In the example below I would like to use the function `mykdeplot()` to make plots for variables `X1` and `X2`.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import random as random

# generate data
group = ['a', 'b']
a = np.random.exponential(4, 10)
b = np.random.exponential(1/4, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': np.repeat(group, 10),
                   'X1': np.random.randint(1,30,20),
                   'X2': np.concatenate((a,b)) })

# plot for X1  
width = 4
sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'a'].X1), bw=width, label = "Group A")
sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'b'].X1), bw=width, label = "Group B")

# plot for X2  
width = 4
sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'a'].X2), bw=width, label = "Group A")
sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'b'].X2), bw=width, label = "Group B")

# Write function (this is where I need help)   
def mykdeplot(var, width):
    sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'a'].var), bw=width, label = "Group A")
    sns.kdeplot(np.array(df[df.Group == 'b'].var), bw=width, label = "Group B")

# call function (does not work)
mykdeplot(df.X1, 3)
mykdeplot(df.X2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mykdeplot(df, var, width):
    sns.kdeplot(np.array(getattr(df[df.Group == 'a'], var)), bw=width, label = "Group A")
    sns.kdeplot(np.array(getattr(df[df.Group == 'b'], var)), bw=width, label = "Group B")

mykdeplot(df, 'X1', 3)
```